# braintree - TokenizeCard not working

Tags: javascript, php, braintree

I am trying to update credit card saved in braintree vault with new values via following code:-

```
var data = {
        cardholderName: $('#cardholder_name').val(),
        expirationDate: $('#expiration_date').val(),
        cvv: $('#cvv').val(),
        billingAddress: {
            firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
            lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
            streetAddress: $('#streetAddress').val(),
            locality: $('#city').val(),
            region: $('#state').val(),
            postalCode: $('#postalCode').val(),
            countryName: $('input[name="country"]').val(),
        }
    };
    if($('#number').prop('disabled') == false) {
        data.number = $('#number').val();
    }
    data.billingAddress['options'] = { updateExisting: true };

var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: "<?=$client_token?>"});
client.tokenizeCard(data, function (err, nonce) {
});
```

The above code works fine when i remove

```
data.billingAddress['options'] = { updateExisting: true };
```

If I include the above line, i receive error Unable to tokenize card. How can I update existing billing address when I tokenize the credit card via javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Braintree. If you need any other help, feel free to reach out to us at support@braintreepayments.com.

When calling `tokenizeCard`, the card and billing address information included in the call isn't added to your vault. Because of this, `updateExisting` shouldn't be used, and will return an error when trying to tokenize the card.

To update an existing credit card, you'll need to pass the nonce you received to your server, then do a `Braintree_PaymentMethod::update()` call to update the information. You'll need to make sure to have the original credit card's token when making this call (which is returned when you first called `Braintree_PaymentMethod::create()` or `Braintree_CreditCard::create())`.